# How to pass display output to serial port under Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, serial-port

We have 2 computer. Fist computer's operating system is Linux( any version( not important for me) ) and another operating system is Windows( any version, i don't care). They are connected via 9 pin serial port.

I want to know how can I change Linux's default display output to serial port instead of it's own monitor. I want to view all Linux outputs( from first word of boot time ) via hyper terminal in Windows XP.

[image: My Problem Image]

BTW it's just a research for future uses ! I know there is no easy solution for doing this. Maybe I should compile Linux again ! I don't know. Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Probably belongs on superuser, perhaps serverfault at a push.

Comment: What do you mean "no, it's not!"? This doesn't seem programming related to me. It's about how to configure your operating system and its consoles / serial ports.

Comment: I need to change ( or even recompile ) Linux kernel code with new parameters and/or new variables. It's not superuser related question! I believe that i should edit Linux kernel which is a programming related question I think!

Comment: If you having difficult with the in _programming_ your linux kernel modifications then that's a completely different - but programming related - question. Your current question is about how to configure you linux system to put the primary console on a serial port. As that's purely a configuration question I still don't see how it's programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly feasible. The easiest way to do this is just to put a "getty" process on the serial terminal, which is sometimes done by editing /etc/inittab (there will be some examples in there) and then you will see a login prompt via the serial terminal and use all (command-line) programs normally. Historically, Unix machines did this as their primary way of working.

Another option is to use the "serial console", which involves passing some boot-time parameters to the kernel; this is only required if you want to see its startup messages on the serial port.

---

Edit: On newer Linux distributions, it's not so easy to put "getty" on a serial line, presumably because it's such an old-fashioned thing to do. Outside of embedded devices, pretty much nobody uses serial ports to log in to the system any more (most modern PCs don't even HAVE rs232 ports). For example, Fedora and Ubuntu do not use "init", but something else which doesn't have inherent support for running "getty". There is probably a way of doing it but I don't know what it is; consult your distributuon's documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and also update. I'm going to search on "getty" process. Which Linux distribution would you suggest ?

Comment: You should not choose your distribution based on this alone, but something which uses a traditional sysv init, not "upstart" or something. Centos 5 would be fine; Ubuntu or Fedora is not.

Comment: I am sure it is possible to get ubuntu/fedora to run getty on a serial port, but you need a different recipe from the widely-documented one.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`console` kernel parameter](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/serial-console.txt) to specify the default console. Add an entry in `inittab` to attach a login process to the serial line.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Serial Console Howto](http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/Serial/serial-console.html)  and use [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) at windows

Comment: I will try putty. Many thanks. Good reference. I'm going to love putty, I think.